# Enable mod_ssl for AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I create AWS Load Balancer. It created successfully.

I also Installed SSL certificate on it. I also enable Https listener for it.

But still my website does not shows https in the URL.

Is it necessary to enable mod_ssl for it?

Or did I miss anything for it?

Please suggest me.

Cheers.

Comment: How have you set up your listeners in Load Balancer?

Comment: @error2007s:- Yes,i also set up listeners

Comment: Can you paste screenshot of your listeners check this one for example http://imgur.com/a/ta7cs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your load balancer to terminate SSL, but do want to handle SSL on your instance, then the SSL listener needs to redirect to port 80 instead of port 443.